# UE4: Cannot create c++ project

Tags: visual-studio-2017, unreal-engine4

as already mentioned I'm using Unreal Engine 4 (v4.15.1).
Now, when i want to create a new c++ project (Basic Code) it begins to generate code but fails to compile it. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 which is supported (ue4 staff confirmed that).

```
Running C:/Program Files/Epic Games/UE_4.15/Engine/Binaries/DotNET/UnrealBuildTool.exe Test Development Win64 -project="D:/Projects/UnrealProjects/Test/Test.uproject" -editorrecompile -progress -NoHotReloadFromIDE
ERROR: System.NotSupportedException: Das angegebene Pfadformat wird nicht unterst?tzt. //translates into 'the given path format is not supported'
bei System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.EmulateFileIOPermissionChecks(String fullPath)
bei System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.QuickDemand(FileIOPermissionAccess access, String fullPath, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath)
bei System.IO.FileInfo.Init(String fileName, Boolean checkHost)
bei UnrealBuildTool.UnrealBuildTool.LoadUBTMakefile(FileReference MakefilePath, FileReference ProjectFile, String& ReasonNotLoaded)
bei UnrealBuildTool.UnrealBuildTool.RunUBT(String[] Arguments, FileReference ProjectFile)
```

Now when I click on 'Open in Visual Studio' it just opens visual studio and imports the ue4 libarys but doesn't do anything else.
When I tried to build a new c++ project again, it works without problems (vs just asks whether it should upgrade the project to 2017 or not).
I installed the c++ 2015 toolchain, IncrediBuild, and the Windown 8.1 SDK.
When I create a new blueprint project and add a c++ class there, it also fails to compile.

```
Running C:/Program Files/Epic Games/UE_4.15/Engine/Binaries/DotNET/UnrealBuildTool.exe  -projectfiles -project="D:/Projects/UnrealProjects/Test/Test.uproject" -game -rocket -progress
(...)
LogVSAccessor:Warning: Couldn't access Visual Studio
Recompiling Test...
Launching UnrealBuildTool... [C:/Program Files/Epic Games/UE_4.15/Engine/Binaries/DotNET/UnrealBuildTool.exe Test -Module Test Win64 Development -editorrecompile -canskiplink "D:/Projects/UnrealProjects/Test/Test.uproject"
(...) 
ERROR: Couldn't find target rules file for target '-canskiplink' in rules assembly 'UE4Rules, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
Location: C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.15\Engine\Intermediate\Build\BuildRules\UE4Rules.dll]
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making an empty blueprint project and adding a C++ class via the editor's File menu, then opening the solution in VS and compiling. Does that work?

Edit: so after some googling (ue4 "-canskiplink"), try making a new project without the name Test. UBT is the build mechanism for UE4, and since the previous build of the code project failed, there may be old UBT files hanging around; when you made the new bp project, UBT didn't see the different project and assumed it was still compiling the code project. I think. So try a new bp project with a different name.

Source: https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/571511/couldnt-find-target-rules-file-for-target-canskipl.html

Comment: Thank you for your help! But I had to uninstall IncrediBuild too!

Comment: Alexander, IncrediBuild is used by hundreds of game developers to accelerate unreal C++ and Shaders compilations (including Epic themselves), we don't have any report from any user regarding a problem such as you describe with IncrediBuild. Can you please contact the IncrediBuild support at: support@incredibuild.com so we can help determine the real problem here and allow you to accelerate your compilations with the product? disclaimer, the writer works at IncrediBuild.